# Error when running eShopOnContainers using Docker and WSL2 on Windows 10 Home: "src_sqldata_1 exited with code 255"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, docker, wsl-2

Whe I try to run [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) using Docker and WSL2 on Windows 10 Home, I am encountering this error:

```
src_sqldata_1 exited with code 255
```

Here are some of the error messages in Docker:

```
2020-09-30 09:47:22.45 spid3s      Starting up database 'msdb'.

2020-09-30 09:47:22.48 spid3s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.

2020-09-30 09:47:22.48 spid3s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file d:\dbs\sh\sqfs\0612_201659\cmd\1r\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

2020-09-30 09:47:22.54 spid3s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.

2020-09-30 09:47:22.54 spid3s      Unable to open the physical file "d:\dbs\sh\sqfs\0612_201659\cmd\1r\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".

2020-09-30 09:47:22.60 spid3s      Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.

2020-09-30 09:47:22.60 spid3s      FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'd:\dbs\sh\sqfs\0612_201659\cmd\1r\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBLog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.

2020-09-30 09:47:22.68 spid3s      File activation failure. The physical file name "d:\dbs\sh\sqfs\0612_201659\cmd\1r\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBLog.ldf" may be incorrect.

2020-09-30 09:47:23.96 spid8s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.

2020-09-30 09:47:24.01 spid8s      The resource database build version is 14.00.3335. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2020-09-30 09:47:24.11 spid8s      Starting up database 'model'.

2020-09-30 09:47:24.13 spid8s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.

2020-09-30 09:47:24.13 spid8s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file d:\dbs\sh\sqfs\0612_201659\cmd\1r\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
```

---

I also tried to run only the `sqldata` container by using `docker-compose up sqldata`, as suggested by @mvelosop [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/1389#issuecomment-671065347) but I am getting the same error:

```
2020-09-30 12:30:51.53 spid19s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2020-09-30 12:30:51.60 spid7s      File activation failure. The physical file name "d:\dbs\sh\sqfs\0612_201659\cmd\1r\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\modellog.ldf" may be incorrect.
2020-09-30 12:30:51.64 spid7s      Error: 945, Severity: 14, State: 2.
2020-09-30 12:30:51.64 spid7s      Database 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
2020-09-30 12:30:51.68 spid7s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
src_sqldata_1 exited with code 255
```

Here are the machine resources it used when I tried to run the `sqldata` container only.

[image]

You can see in that image that I have lots of available RAM left.

I also have lots of disk space left.. more than 100GB in both drive C and D.

Please help. I am not yet very familiar with WSL and Docker.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while running mysql in docker. Few things to take into consideration:

```
1. Increase the memory allocation of docker. 
   You can do it easily using docker desktop dashboard.
2. Run the docker-compose with an admin access.
       For an example: sudo docker-compose -f mysql.docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Point 2 above will resolve inaccessible file issue.

The above I have done it in my MacBook pro 11.5.1